# how to compile vue template in vuejs3

Tags: vuejs3, rollup

I want to develop a vue3 application and use rollup as the bundler. I wrote a vue sfc

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{message}}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'TestComponent',
        setup(){
            const message = '123456';
            return {
                message
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
    .red{
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

and import it in the entry js file.

```
import Test from './Test.vue';

export default function (Vue) {
    Vue.component(Test.name, Test);
}
```

then i installed rollup-plugin-vue to compile vue sfc, postcss and sass to compile sass.

```
const path = require('path');
const inputPath = path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.js');
const outputUMDPath = path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/datav.umd.bundle.js');
const outputESPath = path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/datav.es.bundle.js');
const resolve = require('rollup-plugin-node-resolve');
const commonjs = require('rollup-plugin-commonjs');
const babel = require('rollup-plugin-babel');
const json = require('rollup-plugin-json');
const vue = require('rollup-plugin-vue');
const postcss = require('rollup-plugin-postcss');

export default {
    input: inputPath,
    output: [{
        file: outputUMDPath,
        format: 'umd', 
        name: 'datav-bundle', 
        globals: {
            vue: 'vue'
        }
    }, {
        file: outputESPath,
        format: 'es',
        globals: {
            vue: 'vue'
        }
    }],
    plugins: [
        resolve(),
        commonjs(),
        babel({
            exclude: 'node_modules/**', 
        }),
        json(),
        vue(),
        postcss({
            plugins: []
        })
    ],
    external: [
        'vue'
    ]
}
```

Then IDE reported an error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxyZD.png)

I installed @vue/compiler-sfc as well.

```
"@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.6",
```

but the template was still not compiled.

```
D:\LAB\DataVisualization\libs\src\index.js → dist\datav.umd.bundle.js, dist\datav.es.bundle.js...
[!] (plugin commonjs) SyntaxError: Unexpected token (2:4) in D:\LAB\DataVisualization\libs\src\Test.vue?vue&type=template&id=07bdddea&lang.js
src\Test.vue?vue&type=template&id=07bdddea&lang.js (2:4)
1:
2:     <div>
       ^
3:         {{message}}
4:     </div>
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (2:4) in D:\LAB\DataVisualization\libs\src\Test.vue?vue&type=template&id=07bdddea&lang.js
    at Object.pp$4.raise (D:\LAB\DataVisualization\libs\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:15857:13)
    at Object.pp.unexpected (D:\LAB\DataVisualization\libs\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:13549:8)
    at Object.pp$3.parseExprAtom (D:\LAB\DataVisualization\libs\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:15256:10)
    at Object.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (D:\LAB\DataVisualization\libs\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:15059:19)
```

is there anything i did wrong ?
here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "libs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "rollup -wc rollup.config.dev.js",
    "build": "rollup -c rollup.config.dev.js",
    "build:prod": "rollup -c rollup.config.prod.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.8",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.6",
    "rollup": "^2.40.0",
    "rollup-plugin-babel": "^4.4.0",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^10.1.0",
    "rollup-plugin-json": "^4.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^5.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^4.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.2",
    "rollup-plugin-vue": "^6.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.32.8",
    "vue": "^3.0.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "sam-test-data": "0.0.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, i think maybe i know the reason, i installed rollup-plugin-vue@**6.0.0-beta.6** instead of *@6.0.0, compiled succefully!